# Can a failed update call in MongoDB corrupt the original document?

Tags: mongodb

For example:
Initial call :

```
db.people.update(
   { name: "Andy" },
   {
      name: "Andy",
      rating: 1,
      score: [
           {"year": 2013},
    ]
   },
   { upsert: true }
)
```

and a second call fails, for whatever reason :

```
db.people.update(
   { name: "Andy" },
   {
      score: [
           {"year": 2013},
       {"year": 2017}
    ]
   }
)
```

Can it corrupt the entry or the "score" in any circumstance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> call fails, for whatever reason.
>   Can it corrupt the entry or the "score" in any circumstance?

No, **write operations are atomic with respect to a single document**

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/#what-isolation-guarantees-does-mongodb-provide